# Top Fixing Toilet Seat Bolt won’t unscrew

Tags: bathroom, toilet, bolts

[image]

Any ideas for getting this guy on the left out? When I unscrew it I just hear a squeaking sound. Guessing that the nut has rusted onto the bolt and the whole plastic assembly is turning.

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look underneath to see if that's the case? Maybe you just need to put a wrench on the nut on the bottom to keep it from spinning.

Comment: Do you want to save the black plastic piece?

Comment: Can’t get under it as the toilet itself is hollow with an outer shell if that makes sense. 
Actually the solution was to spray on a load of WD-40 and wait patiently!!! Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Please provide and accept an answer to resolve this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the head or the nut off with a small saw or drill.

I have even used a small hacksaw blade held in a bit of rag and gently cut through like that.

Answer (score 0):

Using a saw, it's easy to scratch the toilet. What i've done in the past for a problem like this was taking a hot soldering iron to push it out through the plastic without unscrewing. Make sure the nut head can be removed w/o the plastic stopping it. This will break the plastic part, but that usually comes with a new seat.

Comment: Presumably with the iron turned on and heated up? You may want to specify that as your answer got flagged by the system for being low quality because it's short. Also, note that the screw head _may_ not pass through the gap in the porcelain, so some care should be used to ensure the toilet doesn't crack.

Comment: Also means the plastic part cannot be reused.

Comment: Screw does appear smaller than the hole...unless you're positing that the holes are not identical.

Comment: That’s a great solution thank you. In the end, a load of WD-40, patience and persistence got it off in the end